# Current timestamp field in mysql table is not updated automatically

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, timestamp, sql-update

I really apologize for asking such a simple question but i am stuck in it. Actually my table has three coloumns such as id, status and date. The date field is current timestamp (Also I have selected on update current timestamp in phpmyadmin).

What I want is that date field should be updated on each update but it is not. Here is my code;

```
if($_POST['status']=="Expired")
    {
        $_POST['remaining']=0;
    }
    if($this->db->update('user_package',$_POST,array('upid'=>$_POST['upid'])))
    {
        redirect('package/view_admin_package_pending');
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Hey I could not update the User's requested Package. I am in Package Controller on line number 406";
    }
```

On update the date field updated as 00000000 instead of correct time and date.So, Can any one help me find out the solution.

NOTE: I have also tried doing bellow but did not work;

```
$_POST['date']=now();
```

also tried

```
$_POST['date']=time();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in SQL directly like this

```
update your_table
set some_column = 1,
    `date` = current_timestamp
where ...
```

Answer (score 2):

function is enough for this code.

```
$data = array(
               'content_header' => $_POST['content_header'],
                'content_body' => $_POST['content_body'],
                'content_footer' => $_POST['content_footer'],
                'post_catagory' => $_POST['post_catagory']
                'update_time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there was problem in my projects. Theoretically and logically, Current timestamp (specially on update timestamp selected) automatically updates the date field to current timestamp. So, My code was right but I have confusion in my projects. Anyhow, I appreciate every one's Answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use $_POST. Codeigniter provides useful way to get $_POST variables:

```
$my_update = array();
$my_update['status'] = $this->input->post('status');//in controller
```

...
add there all your variables from the form in the same way
...
After you will decide to update your table, set all the variables you need

```
$data = array(
  'status' => $my_update['status'],
  //...
);
```

To set your where condition, better use codeigniter tool:
    $this->db->where('upid', $my_update['upid']);
After that, add a date field update:
    $this->db->set('created', 'now()');
And then you can update your table:

```
$this->db->update('user_package', $my_update);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('23.12.2013 15:23:23'));`